# python-2.7 .zip multiple generated lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Lets say I have a function that generates X amount of equal length lists based on function call. e.g if there are 5 separate strings in function call it should generate 5 lists and .zip/join/merge them into one.

To accomplish this i am using this mockup function:

```
def FetchData(*args):
   returnlist = []
   for arg in args:
      datalist = generate.list(arg) #obviously not a real method.

      if returnlist == []
          returnlist = datalist 
      else:
          returnlist = map(list, zip(returnlist, datalist))

    return returnlist
```

This works fine if there are 0, 1 or 2 arguments.
However, IF there are more, things get weird:

Here is a sample result when FetchData() gets 4 arguments:

```
>>> returnlist[0]
>>> [[['a', 'b'], 'c'], 'd']
```

But i need:

```
>>> ['a','b','c','d']
```

I sorta fixed it by 'strigifying' each returnlist item and removing extra symbols, but that seems way too crude.

I am sure there is a way to properly .zip the generated lists without the need to comprehend the result afterwards.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you're  trying to write your own: [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (or something very similar)

Comment: no, more along the lines of itertools.izip However that does not work in a loop and i still get the aforementioned result. To recap,i am trying to get one zipped list out of unknown amount of lists. Hence the loop.

Comment: so given `[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8 9]` what is the output required?

Comment: ['1 4 7', '2 5 8', '3 6 9'] . Sorry for being unclear.. first time posting.

Comment: But you need them as strings? Looks like you just want to flatten a list of lists?

Comment: ah yes.. Flatten is exactly what i need.  Never herd of that before. thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following:

```
from itertools import chain
def fetch_data(*args):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*args)))

a = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7, 8, 9] ]

print fetch_data(*a)
# [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

Or, `return map(list, zip(*args))` will give you: `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`